# I want to make a custom slider

Tags: slider, visible, jcarousellite

I made a simple slider by [jcarousellite](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jCarouselLite) but i need to make something else:

I need the first visible image to be large what should i do ? 
Or how i can select the first visible image in slider?

Answer (score 0):

```
@option start : number - default is 0 @example $(".carousel").jCarouselLite({
     btnNext: ".next",
     btnPrev: ".prev",
     start: 2 }); @desc You can specify from which item the carousel should start. Remember, the first item in the carousel has a start of 0, and so on.
```